# Integrate Blog Into Website

Tags: html, web, blogs, blogger

I currently have a blog at blogger.com and was wondering if there is anyway to integrate my blog into a website I have built, rather than just embedding it using an iframe.. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use an rss feed from your blogsite to generate a layout on your site using Javascript/Html/CSS

Comment: Thanks I did try the RSS feed but dont like the way it lays it out

Comment: you can extract the data from the rss feed and lay it out how youd like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Blogger Data API with JSON feed instead of iframe to fetch important data such as Post Summary, Title, Timestamp, Comments count, Thumbnail image, Label List, Author info and so on. You can use their anywhere inside your site.
JSON feed is a lightweight and allow you to fetch data much more faster compared to XML which use in RSS and Atom feed.
[This is good tutorials to start with Blogger JSON feed.](http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2015/10/introduction-to-blogger-json-feeds-and-blogger-data-api.html)

Comment: Thank you I will try this out